# htaccess authentication exclude specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii

I tried several solutions on stackoverflow itself but none of them is working. I have no idea why..
 Here is what I need, I added basic auth for my test site. here is my htaccess file

```
   #allows a single uri through the .htaccess password protection
   SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/webservice/ noauth=1
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

   AuthName "Restricted Area"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile "/xxx/.htpasswd"
   Require valid-user
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from env=noauth
   Satisfy any
   </IfModule>
```

From other references, above mentioned configuration should allow webservice URL to bypass basic auth But it is not happening. 
I'm using apache 2.4.7 and development is Yii 1.1

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Your code should work as it is. Try clearing your browser cache. If this doesn't help then, try removing the Satisfy directive.

Comment: That was it..  I cleared all the cache, restarted browser and it working as expected.. ! ..  Thanks...